# Differentiate the integral $\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x} \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \rho u_{tt} {\rm d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

In Partial Differential Equations by Walter Strauss, Ch 1.3 Example 2, the author differentiates the integral $$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \rho u_{tt} {\rm d}x$$ with respect to $x$ and finds that

$$\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x} \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \rho u_{tt} {\rm d}x=\rho u_{tt}$$

Why is this the case ? Did they use the Leibniz integral rule or the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: Are you sure that $\int_{x_0}^{x_1} \rho u_{tt}dx$ is a constant? There could be a typo as well.

Comment: does $u_{tt}$ not depend on $x$?

Comment: Check the second edition: http://jingweizhu.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/5/4/13548262/partial-differential-equations.pdf, pages 11-13.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I think but am not sure that $x_1$ and $x_0$ are constants so that if you evaluated the integral there would be no $x$ remaining. Then when you take the derivative you should get zero.

Comment: @tail_recursion Indeed, I am not even able to make head or tail of the Strauss explanation.

Comment: I think I figured it out.

Comment: @tail_recursion If you figured it out then kindly tell me.

Comment: I posted an answer to this question which might help explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its just the fundamental theorem of calculus. $x_1$ is a variable and you treat $x_0$ as fixed so when you differentiate the integral you get $\rho u_{tt}|^{x=x_1}$ and differentiating $T{u_x}|_{x_0}^{x_1}$ wrt $x_1$ is the same as differentiating $T{u_x}$ wrt x and then evaluating at $x_1$ so you get $(T{u_x})_x|^{x_1}$. Therefore $Tu_x=\rho u_{tt}$

Comment: I think the problem contains some typos as the integration variable is also taken as $x$